# SonarQube 4.3.2 not releasing Oracle DB connections

Tags: sonarqube

Since the sonar upgrade from 3.4.1 to 4.3.2, we are noticing that the database sessions are not being closed after the process. We have been using the default setting of 20 connections limit, however  after the upgrade, we found we were consuming 20 connections in few hours and hence had to restart the server few times a day.

## Error from log

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a     connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object 
### The error may exist in org.sonar.core.source.db.SnapshotDataMapper
```

After bumping sonar.jdbc.maxActive to 250, we still have to restart the Sonar server daily to have sonar operational.

Any insight/advise in this issue will be much appreciated.

## Environment

DataBase : Oracle 11.2 server with ojdbc6.jar(the latest one from Oracle site)

Java:  JDK1.7

## Sonar.properties

### Connection pool settings

```
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=250 
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=25 
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2 
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000 
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000 
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
```

### Plugins list

```
sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.1.jar   
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.2.jar   
sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.3.jar   
sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.3.jar   
sonar-java-plugin-2.3.jar   
sonar-javascript-plugin-1.6.jar   
sonar-pmd-plugin-2.2.jar   
sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.3.jar   
sonar-surefire-plugin-2.3.jar
```

## wrapper.conf

```
# Java Additional Parameters 
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true 
wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:MaxPermSize=160m 
wrapper.java.additional.3=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djruby.management.enabled=false 

# Maximum amount of memory of Java VM 
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Xmx2048M 

# RECOMMENDED : uncomment if Java Virtual Machine is a JDK but not a JRE. To know which JVM you use, execute 
# 'java -version'. JDK displays 'Server VM'. 
wrapper.java.additional.7=-server 

# Initial JVM heap size (in MB) 
wrapper.java.initmemory=1024 

#******************************************************************** 
# Wrapper Java Properties 
#******************************************************************** 
# JVM 
# Can be an absolute path, for example: 
#wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java 
#wrapper.java.command=java 
wrapper.java.command=/ENTIRE_PATH/jdk1.7/bin/java 

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface 
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper 
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section 
#  of the documentation for details. 
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp 

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as 
#  needed starting from 1 
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/*.jar 
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../conf 
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/h2/*.jar 
wrapper.java.classpath.4=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/mysql/*.jar 
wrapper.java.classpath.5=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/*.jar 
wrapper.java.classpath.6=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/postgresql/*.jar 
wrapper.java.classpath.7=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql/*.jar 

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so) 
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib 

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1 
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.StartServer 

# Do not touch the following property. Max memory is set with -Xmx (see above). 
# See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5204
wrapper.java.maxmemory=0
```

Comment: I am facing the same error with SonarQube-4.5.1 using Oracle as DB, Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You say "the database sessions are not being closed after the process". Which process is it? Are these database connections opened during code analysis or just for the day-to-day consulting of the SonarQube dashboards (or both)?

How do you launch your analisis ? Sonar-Runner or Jenkins? Have you change something in your configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with this issue, where Sonar starts up and in few minutes it has used upto 12 db connections. Any subsequent DB connection opened to load the dashboard or to do an API query, sonarqube is not closing previously opened sessions. As these connections are abandoned and are piling up and eventually I run out of connections in the pool which leads to the error.

```
  Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a     connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object 
  The error may exist in org.sonar.core.source.db.SnapshotDataMapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Any database connection that is being created is not closed. For code Analysis, Rest API calls and dashboard rendering type connections.

Analysis is triggered as Jenkins job once a day.